# installing php5 with php7 already install

Tags: apache2, php

I would like to install php5 but keep the php7 that is already installed. I need php5 to mainly edit and update an older site (mainly a joomla site) and updates to get to php7. Might have to rune php5 for a small time.

I have installed apt-get install *software-properties-common* and *ppa:ondrej/php* (which is up to date).

The php7 is in /etc/php/php7.2

Will running sudo *apt-get install -y php5.6* install into a new directory in the  /etc/php/ ?

And, will it make php7 stop?

If not, should I go ahead and run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-sqlite3 libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

Ubuntu 18.04.6

Comment: Please add details.  What version of Ubuntu are you on?  For what reason or for what application do you need/want php5?

Comment: updated details...

Comment: I have done the same thing long ago and will look if I have notes.  For the same thing.  I would wait for a more definitive answer.  Best case is you install and it goes into /etc/php/5.6.  Worst case it uninstalls 7.2 which you can reinstall.  I recommend you make a copy of the whole php folder to replace if needed. If I recall when I was on Server 16.04 and ondre's ppa I had multiple php versions and the application just used what it needed.

Comment: You can use [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) PPA repository. It will allow You to instal few major php versions side by side.

Comment: Got it to work with the data for installing php5.6 and switched apache to use the php5.6 module. Had to install other dependencies the site needed (phpCURL, etc...)